# pydev using debug got error ,how to resolve?

Tags: django, debugging, pydev

```
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 21100)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python tools\eclipse-java-oxygen-3a-win32-x86_64\eclipse\dropins\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_6.3.2.201803171248\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1621, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\python tools\eclipse-java-oxygen-3a-win32-x86_64\eclipse\dropins\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_6.3.2.201803171248\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1615, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "D:\python tools\eclipse-java-oxygen-3a-win32-x86_64\eclipse\dropins\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_6.3.2.201803171248\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1022, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\python\django\webapp\app01\views.py", line 12, in <module>
    from app01.models import  FristModel
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\python\django\webapp\app01\models.py", line 8, in <module>
    class FristModel (models.Model):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.13-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\base.py", line 110, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.13-py2.7.egg\django\apps\registry.py", line 247, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.13-py2.7.egg\django\apps\registry.py", line 125, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Comment: show your django settings files

Answer (score 0):

There can b multiple reason of this error.

1. There can be any app in `INSTALLED_APPS` which does not exist.
2. LOGGING a filename in a non-existent directory
3. There can be miss `,` in `INSTALLED_APPS` each app separation.